# Seat does not get updated in DB

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am a beginner in c# and trying to make a simple software. I have a table in which `"id"` is the primary key. If I select 2 passengers, both of them will have same Booking ID but different `"id"("id"` is being auto generated by SQL and increments for next customer). What I want is one button click, seats should get updated with respect to booking ID. Here is the code I have made so far. I have inserted selected seat names in the Listbox. I tried displaying `id,bookingID` and Items of ListBox in `messagebox` and everything was where it needs to be. Thanks.

```
onclick()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) //m is the number of seats in listbox
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("update Final set Seat=@Seat where id=@id and BookingID=@BookingID", con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BookingID", JourneyDetails.bookId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seat", listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        id++;
        con.Close();

    }


    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: "What I want is, one button click, seats should get updated with respect to booking ID." I mentioned dude. Now when I am pressing button, seats column shows null and does not gets updated.

Comment: How many accounts do you have? Obviously you're same as user8340731

Comment: Well, I'd guess that the @Seat column is null because, if you put a breakpoint on the AddwithValue method, the ToString() returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` before you close the connection in `con.Close()`.

Comment: Thanks, you are somewhere right. After adding cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() , the first id has seat got others seat name and later id has seat NULL. Any other change please

Comment: Use multiple ids. You are updating only a single row in your loop because of `id = @id` condition in query.

Comment: But I have i++. So why does not the next id's row gets updated.?

Comment: Alright, I had missed that. It could be because you IDs are like 1, 3, 5, 7. One increment will not give you the next row's id.